# scroll bar not working in chrome but working in firefox

Tags: html

when the website is open in chrome the wheel of mouse doesn't work but when open in firefox the wheel of mouse is automatically works..I tried many code and tricks to change but it doesn't work properly

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried. Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of the js file is conflicting with code.
If we [disable js execution on chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0/5PRO2P-1WWwJ)  it works completely fine.

Try commenting `<script src="./Home_files/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>` line to bring back scroll capability.